# GAS all Triggers disabled suddenly. why?

Tags: google-apps-script

all my GAS triggers (time based) in all my projects are disabled:
checking the trigger page shows a red "Disabled" under "last run"

and text inside says:
Disable reason
You do not have access to the target script.

can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Are you the owner of the files and projects? Or have the respective files have been shared with you by the owner?

Answer (score 2):

### The error you obtained is caused by the following constellation

- User A created a file
- User A shared his file with user B
- User B either created a bound script and attached an time-driven trigger to the script, or User B attached a time-driven to the script created by user A
- User A stopped sharing the file with user B
- User B is not allowed anymore to use a trigger on User A's file
- User B's triggers become disabled and show the Disable reason "You do not have access to the target script."