# GAS triggers randomly disabling after being created programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created a few trigger chains that fire at specific times over a weekend.  I have chained them due to the limit of 20 timed triggers available to me.

Randomly a newly created trigger on the chain will become disabled and therefore not run.  Obviously this ruins the entire chain and completely messes up what I'm trying to achieve.

I thought there may have been an issue in the ordering of exactly *when* I created the new trigger in the code, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm wondering whether deleting a trigger within the script that it calls may be the cause of the issue - but I cannot think of an alternative way to code it.

Here's a portion of the chain code:

```
function mastersResultsAmericas1() {
  var region   = "Americas";
  var rSpot    = 1;
  var bgcolour = "#ffe1bc";

  mrAmericasTC2();
  mastersResults(region, rSpot, bgcolour);
  delTrigger("mastersResultsAmericas1");
}


function mrAmericasTC2() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("mastersResultsAmericas2")
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(9)
    .nearMinute(50)
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.SATURDAY)
    .inTimezone("PST8PDT")
    .create();
}
```

They chain all the way up to `5` and then that resets and creates the `1` trigger once again.

Here is the code I use to delete the triggers:

```
function delTrigger(trigger) {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++){ 
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction().indexOf(trigger) != -1) 
    {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518831/gas-all-triggers-disabled-suddenly-why) link referring to disabled triggers - but the answer is not applicable to me.  I am the *only* user and the *only* person who has access to the spreadsheet.

Comment: There is an issue on the Issue Tracker at: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142405165](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142405165)

Comment: Thanks Alan!  I don't know if that's handy to know or not.  100 people have tagged they have a problem with it, and no followup whatsoever.  First time I've accessed the Issue Tracker so I may have missed something.

Comment: There have been issues with triggers silently failing for years.  I'm not sure it it's worse recently.  I've literally been complaining about it for years.

Comment: There seem to be some gaping holes in Google Docs in general.  Limited to 20 timed triggers.  Not being able to see when a trigger is going to fire next, etc.  I've only had this problem with the trigger chain - and it's the first chain I've created.  A dozen other triggers have fired for a year and a half without a single one of them going disabled.  Building a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was a result of the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781711/scheduling-google-app-script-function-for-specific-recurring-windows) question.

Basically I just built code into an existing trigger that checked the day/time and ran the specific function if conditions were met.  No longer need the trigger chain, nor to create any extra triggers programmatically (other than the initial setup).